# Domain controller could not be contacted

Tags: active-directory, domain

Attempting to add a new server to our domain and it refuses to join, the error is

```
The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "Ragonz.domain":

The error was: "This operation returned because the timeout period expired."
(error code 0x000005B4 ERROR_TIMEOUT)

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.Ragonz.domain

The DNS servers used by this computer for name resolution are not responding. This computer is configured to use DNS servers with the following IP addresses:

110.168.19.24

Verify that this computer is connected to the network, that these are the correct DNS server IP addresses, and that at least one of the DNS servers is running.
```

Now I know the domain is fine as I've just joined another server to it without issue but this box refuses to join. IP config/all below

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Australia179
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : Ragonz.domain

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Ragonz.domain
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection
#3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-25-90-5F-2A-F8
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 119.253.189.199(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 119.253.189.254
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 110.168.19.24

   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Ping - comes back fine

```
Reply from 110.168.19.24: bytes=32 time=304ms TTL=115
Reply from 110.168.19.24: bytes=32 time=304ms TTL=115

Ping statistics for 110.168.19.24:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 304ms, Maximum = 304ms, Average = 304ms
```

NSLookup

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup Ragonz.domain
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  110.168.19.24
```

FYI - I've had to change the IP's/Domain above for privacy so they are not real however as mentioned only this machine has the problem, all other machines can join the domain without issue.

Any idea's?

Comment: The DNS settings are correct, all network settings are identical (other than the IP/Subnet for obvious reasons) to another server which is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was the provider had blocked a port required to join that machine to the domain. As I mentioned several times in the question/replies it was not a DNS error.

Comment: +1, In my case, the static MAC address table on the switch is the problem. I delete the system MAC address that had joined already manually and now I can connect to the AD server.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (AWS Infrastructure), issue with that the DC servers security group not added with the client servers IP source which are failing to communicate / resolve DNS with DC servers.

After adding Inbound rule by allowing client servers Subnet CIDR with in DC servers security group, able to resolve DNS and join the client servers into the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the DNS settings are the same for the working PC and the one you have the timeout, seems like a DNS issue.

As you can see in your log:

> The DNS servers used by this computer for name resolution are not
>   responding. This computer is configured to use DNS servers with the
>   following IP addresses ...

Comment: Indeed. The error specifically calls out a timeout waiting for a host to be resolved.  In addition, the OP's NSLOOKUP attempt failed, which means either the DNS server isn't operating correctly, or the ports used to contact it are blocked.   

Is this system situated behind a firewall? One would need to ensure that DNS traffic is allowed in both directions across that firewall, or the new box will never be able to resolve anything beyond it.

Comment: The DNS settings are correct, all network settings are identical (other than the IP/Subnet for obvious reasons) to another server which is working fine.

Comment: Anyone else got any idea's? Have a server that just will not join the domain despite being set up in an identical way to another which does join the domain.